# What is the difference between " required" and " need" ? And which is the right place/situation to use this?

Tags: modal-verbs, adverbs

Usually when I talk and write a mail I am doubtful to use " required" or " need" for the situation. please help me clear understanding of the place and situation to use it properly.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

*Need* is clearly more intensive. If you *need* something, it's pretty crucial. On the other hand, if you *require* something, it could be just helpful.

To quote [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/need_1?q=need),

> to require something/somebody because they are essential or very important, ***not just because you would like to have them***

So, *food* is our ***need*** and not *requirement.*

Nevertheless, you are writing an email where both can be interchanged in most of the cases.

Note: I may tell you specifically if you tell me where exactly you find it difficult.